# How to implement a html file into a python tkinter window?

Tags: javascript, python, html, tkinter, web

so i wanted to implement my html webpage project into a python tkinter window, using tkinter html view.

but when i attempted to do exactly that, i get this  (python tkinter window) [what im geting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2srF.png)

but this is how i originally made it to look like (in browser, the colors are messed up because of my client side settings) [supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XJdk.png)

so here is my python code in "app.py":

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkhtmlview import HTMLText, RenderHTML

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Youtube")
root.geometry("1200x600")
html_label = HTMLText(root, html=RenderHTML('OpenMe.html'))
html_label.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
html_label.fit_height()
root.mainloop()
```

and here is my html "OpenMe.html" code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      
      <!--
            page version number 16.10
        -->
      
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>HTML GIZMO!</title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
      <style>
        
          
          .buttn {
            transition: 0.2s;
            height: 100px;
            width: 200px;
            color: white;
            border-color: black;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background-color: transparent;
            border-width: 3px;
            click: pointer;
        }
        
        button {
            transition: 0.2s;
            height:100px;
            width:200px;
            color: white;
            border-color: white;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background-color: transparent;
            border-width: 2px;
        }
        
        button:hover {
            transition: 0.2s;
            height:150px;
            width:300px;
            color: black;
            border-color: white;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background-color: white;
            border-width: 2px;
        }
        
        .buttn:hover {
            transition: 0.2s;
            height:150px;
            width:250px;
            color: white;
            border-color: white;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background-color: transparent;
            border-width: 2px;
        }
          
          
          
        body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }
          
          hr {
        width: 15%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
          
         .title { font-size: 80px; }

                .navi {
            transition: 0.2s;
            height:50px;
            width:100px;
            color: white;
            border-color: white;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background-color: transparent;
            border-width: 2px;
        }
        
        .navi:hover {
            transition: 0.2s;
            height:75px;
            width:150px;
            color: black;
            border-color: white;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background-color: white;
            border-width: 2px;
        }
          
          </style>
    <script>

        function hm(){
            location.href="./OpenMe.html"
        }
        function game(){
            location.href="./games/games.html"
        }
        function tools(){
            location.href="./tools/tools.html"  
        }
        function sett(){
            location.href="./settings.html" 
        }
        function cre(){
            location.href="./info/credits.html" 
        }
        
function Startup(){
    //Time//
    const date = new Date();
    const hour = date.getHours();
    const mins = date.getMinutes();
    document.getElementById("CConsole").innerHTML = hour+":"+mins;  
}
        
    </script>
  </head>
   <body bgcolor="#050505" onload="Startup();">
       <center><nav><font color = "white">
           <br>
            <button class="navi" style="background-color:white;color:black;" onclick="hme();">Home</button>   <button class="navi" onclick="game();">Games</button> <button class="navi" onclick="tools();">Tools</button> <button class="navi" onclick="cre();"> Updates </button>
           
       </nav></center>
      <center><p class="title"><font color="lime"> H<font color="blue">T<font color="purple">M<font color="red">L<font color="orange"> G<font color="orange">I<font color="lime">Z<font color="red">M<font color="orange">O<font color="yellow">!<font color="white"></p>
          <h1>What's New:</h1>
          -Made UI Changes<br>
          -Added a New Game<br>
          -Fixed Bugs
          <font color="grey"><h4><center>Version 0.1.10.00.000</center></h4></center>
  </body>
</html>
```

can someone with this pleasae? i am pretty new to python and especially tkinter it would really help alot!

Comment: `tkhtmlview` does not support `<style>`.  Use [`tkinterweb.HtmlFrame`](https://github.com/Andereoo/TkinterWeb/blob/main/tkinterweb/docs/HTMLFRAME.md). Note that JavaScript is not supported.